# What does Marcus do with GenIVIV?

Tags: borderlands-3

At the end of the mission "The Family Jewel" Marcus asks you to hand him over the hard drive with GenIVIV on it since he has "some use" for it.

While you're on your way BALEX also mentions that you should install her into a "Toilet or even better, a broken toilet so she can't do any harm" and Marcus just responds with "Ah! I know just the place!"

So obviously Marcus has the AI and he has plans for her but what exactly does he do with her?

I've completed the mission multiple times and I've searched the entire ship but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows this at this point. Mabe it will come up in a DLC.

Comment: @Dennisch Maybe, but I wouldn't be surprised if she's currently hidden somewhere on the Sanctuary or on a planet (or in a broken toilet). BL does that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it seems like Marcus doesn't do anything after receiving GenIVIV.

The only real interaction the player has with GenIVIV is in the [Messy Breakup](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Messy_Breakup) shield her character may drop upon death. The shield makes quips about your character such as being jealous of Claptrap or complaining about taking damage - a very similar personality to GenIVIV.

Apart from that, all interactions with GenIVIV seem to disappear after handed over to Marcus. It may be possible she returns on DLC content or a future installment of the franchise.